# How do you prove a form is exact and/or closed

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

So I know that a one form $\alpha$ is exact if $\alpha= df$ for some smooth $f$.

In other words, if you can take a derivative of a function and get the 1-form, the 1-form is exact?

So, how would one go about proving something like

$$a = 2x dx + dy$$

is exact?

If we assume $df$ is $2x dx + dy$ then wouldn't $f$ be $x^2 + y$? Since the derivative of $x^2$ will be $2x$ and the derivative of $y$ would be $1$?

All I have about 1-forms being closed is the following information:

$\alpha = adx + bdy$ with $da/dy = db/dx$ is closed. The definition of closed was introduced in the homework and I have no idea how to actually do one of these (since I have not seen any examples), could someone maybe point me to a source and or video describing this?

Comment: A form $\alpha$ is closed if $d\alpha=0$. This is easy to check. You have a necessary, not sufficient condition, for exactness, since $ddf=0$ for all $f$.

Comment: Sweet! That makes a little more sense, but how would I go about showing that 2xdx + dy is exact?

Comment: Everything I see online is about exact differential equations where you have something dx + something dy and if you take the derivative of the first piece with respect to y and the derivative of the second piece with respect to x and get the same answer for both, then it is exact. Will I do that here since the derivative of 2x with respect to y is 0 and the derivative of 1 with respect to x is 0, therefore they are the same, and exact?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know some basic things about differential forms, like the exterior derivative ($\mathrm{d}$) and the wedge product ($\wedge$). Otherwise, I really have no clue how one can prove such a statement (because it is about differential forms...)

We have the fact that if a $1$-form is exact, then it is closed, as if $\alpha = \mathrm{d}f$, then $\mathrm{d}\alpha = \mathrm{d}^2 f = 0$ (recall that $\mathrm{d}^2=0$). It is in fact true for $k$-forms : if a $k$-form $\beta$ is the exterior derivative of a $(k-1)$-form, then $\mathrm{d}\beta=0$.
The converse is, in general, false.

Here is a partial converse: the Poincaré lemma states that, if $M$ is a contractible manifold, then every closed exact form is exact.

In your example, I assume you are working on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, let $f(x,y) = x^2 + y$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}f &= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= 2x\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{d}y
\end{align}
so $2x\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{d}y$ is exact. But we could have looked at $\mathrm{d}\left(2x\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{d}y \right)$: we would have noticed that it is zero, and thus, the Poincaré lemma would have said that there exists $g$ such that $\mathrm{d}g = 2x\mathrm{d}x+\mathrm{d}y$, because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible. There exist infinitly many $g$ such that $\mathrm{d}g = 2x\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{d}y$ (they all differ by some constant function).

In particular, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the Poincaré lemma says that a $1$-form is closed if and only if it is exact. Let $\alpha = a(x,y) \mathrm{d}x + b(x,y)\mathrm{d}y$ be a $1$-form. Then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}\alpha = 0 & \iff \mathrm{d}\left(a(x,y) \mathrm{d}x + b(x,y)\mathrm{d}y \right)= 0 \\
&\iff \left((\partial_x a)\mathrm{d}x + (\partial_y a) \mathrm{d}y\right)\wedge \mathrm{d}x + \left((\partial_x b)\mathrm{d}x + (\partial_y b)\mathrm{d}y \right)\wedge \mathrm{d}y = 0 \\
&\iff (\partial_ya)\mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}x + (\partial_xb) \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y = 0 \\
& \iff \left(\partial_x b - \partial_y a \right)\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y = 0 \\
&\iff \partial_y a = \partial_x b
\end{align}
And $\alpha$ is exact if and only if $\alpha$ is closed, if and only if $\partial_ya = \partial_x b$.

Comment: We have talked about the exterior derivative, but not about the wedge product. 

Here is the information from class

For smooth f: U to R, there exists  unique 1-form df with the property that df(v) = v[f] for any vector fields v on u. df is the exterior derivative of f. When "alpha" = dg, for some g, then this alpha is exact. 

The example was 

If f = 2x1^2x2-1 then df is 4x1x2dx1 + 2x1^2dx2

Then for example, df(d/dx1) = 4x1x2 and v[f] = d/dx1 ( 2x1^2z2 - 1) = 4x1x2 and then checkmarks by both 4x1x2's to show that they are the same.

Comment: @Nono4271 Please use LaTeX, it is quite hard to follow your comments

Comment: I am unsure of the correct way to type this in Latex, so I took a picture. https://imgur.com/a/0WJ0kDr